# Querying hstore with exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, hstore

I have a column as `postgres hstore`, and want to query it with exists? in my model.

I am using

```
Model.where("column ? :key", key: "xxx").count
```

but effectively I just want to know if there at least one with that key, something like

```
Contact.exists?("column? :key", key: "xxx")
```

which results an error, because `exists?` has on argument only.

Any hints?

Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, simply:

Model.where("column ? :key", key: "xxx").exists?

results in a query with LIMIT 1.